# When there isn't any Zend Json Object console throws 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, json, zend-framework2

I'm using an action from *LoginController.php*:

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('LoginForm');
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $form->setData($post);
    $response   = $this->getResponse();

    if (!$form->isValid()){
        // something is invalid; print the reasons
        $json= $form->getMessages();
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($json));
        return $response;
    } else {
        $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()->setIdentity(
            $this->request->getPost('email'))->setCredential(
            $this->request->getPost('password'));
        $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
        switch ($result->getCode()) {
            case Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND:
            $json = "Email or password is incorrect";
            $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($json));
            return $response;
            case Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
            $json = "Email or password is incorrect";
            $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($json));
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

and I get these Encoded `$json` values in *script.js*:

```
$('#navLogin').removeAttr('style');
$('#labelLogin').css('display', 'none');

$("#Login input").blur(function()
{
    $("#formLoginErrorMessage").children().remove();
    var formElementId = $(this).parent().find('input').attr('id');
    doValidation(formElementId);
});

function doValidation(id, url)
{
    var url = 'ajax/';
    var data = {};
    $('input').each(function()
    {
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); 
    });
    $.post(url,data,function(resp)
    {
        $('#'+id).parent().find('.alert-danger').remove();
        if(resp === null)
        {
            console.log("Dang");
        }else if (typeof resp === "object") {
            $('#'+id).parent().find('.alert-danger').remove();
            $('#'+id).parent().append(getErrorHtml(resp[id], id));
            console.log(resp);
          } else {
            $("#formLoginErrorMessage").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#formLoginErrorMessage").append("<li>" + resp + "</li>");
            console.log(resp);
          }
    },'json');
}

function getErrorHtml(formErrors, id)
{
    var o = '<ul id="errors-'+id+'" class="alert-danger">';
    for(errorKey in formErrors)
    {
        o += '<li>' + formErrors[errorKey] + '</li>';
    }

    o+= '</ul>';
    return o;
}
```

Using **ajaxAction** i encode error messages from a login form that might appear and pass them in `$.post(url,data,function(resp){`..., where **resp** is encoded object from php.

**Problem** When there are nothing to encode in Google Developer Tools I get:

> POST http://new.local/login/ajax/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Fix** By adding this to LoginController.php i don't get a 500 Error and can process JSON object.

```
if(!isset($json)){
        $json = " ";
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($json));
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your console doesn't throw a 500 error, your server-side PHP code does. Debug your PHP to find out where and why.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you suggest a normal PHP Debugger.

Comment: What did you see in your error log?

Comment: Here https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/895x104q90/661/OABpjv.png is what console shows.

Comment: Not the console. Your PHP error log.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Do you mean when i open page ? If so then i don't have any eror.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen to fully understand my problem here is http://test-site.6te.net/login/ and in this website after writing e-mail:stackoverflow@gmail.com and password:Stack147 in Google Developer Tools it will show this error.

Comment: Seeing what's reported on the client does not help at all. You have a server side error. Locate your PHP error log and look for the error.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen  Undefined variable: json. This notice is in last rows. That notice appears when i include `var_dump($json);` at the end of ajaxAction.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen error was because there wasn't any object and tried to get JSON object using `$.post..`. Added what is written in **Fix** block and now there is no error.